# Web API 2 Routing - should ID's always be included even if they are not necessary?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, routes

So this is more of a design question, but i think it is one worth questioning.

Here is my dilemma. I am ending up with some quite complex routing while designing an API for consumption. here is an example:

```
Route("/people/{personID}/phonenumber/{phoneNumberID}/operation/{operationID}/data")
```

Now this route gets data performed in an operation for a specific phone number for a specific person.

Due to the fact that i can get the operation data solely by the operationID, I really do not need to include personID, or phonenumberID. However this data is tied directly to all of the ID's that are previous to it.  Thus, creates "chain of command" if you will.

For instance i could still drop the operationID to get all operations performed on a specific phone number. Like so:

```
Route("/people/{personID}/phonenumber/{phoneNumberID}/operation")
```

In this case, the PhoneNumberID is now relevant and needed in order to get the operations neccessary.  In the previous example `PhoneNumberID` did not do anything due to the fact that i had the explict `operationID` to retrieve data for.

On to my question already!

SO! Should i always include all id's in the route even if they are not needed to actually retrieve the data?  Or is this a case of poor design and I should really just rethink how I am doing this? Something just feels off in my gut.

Comment: i would personally use /operation/{operationID} in your first situation since you want to retrieve an operation and possess the OperationID

Answer (score 0):

You should try to follow RESTful design. If it's not needed for the resource someone is trying to consume then leave it out. Try to make the API as clear and simple as possible.

If you need to create complex or more detailed API methods you can always have those served via a HTTP POST request for large responses.

Keep things simple. Keep the API clean. Clear well defined Controllers that only take what is necessary for that specific resource.

Comment: When you say RESTful design, are you talking querystring vs in-url variables?

Comment: RESTful in design with regards to GET/PUT/POST/DELETE naming conventions with urls and how you access or create a resource.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you. However, How do you deal with resources that are tied tied across multiple controllers/entities?  can i now access "operations" through my person controller, phone controller and deticated operations controller?  or do i take those dependencies into my operations controller.  Also, i don't want to use a POST to retrieve data just because my query is complex.  That is not what the POST method is meant to do. Simplicty is great, but so is structure. That is what i am struggling with.